# Selenium::Python::Pop Up Window

Tags: python, selenium, popup, eventhandler

I am trying to automate some basic web browser manipulation. As part of this sequence there is a popup window that must be dealt with. Once the python code the causes the popup window to appear happens, no other code past that point will run until I manually close that window. Then all remaining code runs fine.

I've try this below to try to deal with handling the popup but to no avail:

```
for handle in browser.window_handles:
     print "Handle = ",handle
     browswer.switch_to_window(handle);
     elem=browser.find_element_by_tag_name("title")
     print elem.get_attrbitue("value")
```

I cannot even get a basic 'print' command to execute until I close the popup window. Is there a need to set some type of event handler BEFORE the code is called that brings the popup menu?

Thanks for any suggestions.